# Opensearchserver database crawl

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL table (tbl_test) with 4 columns - **id**, **url**, **title** & **description**. There are 39409 rows in the table. I would like to index this table into Opensearchserver v1.5.3, I have created a new index with the 'web crawler' template and my database crawler settings are as follows:-

```
General settings
```

**Name:** test_crawl

**Driver class:** com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

**JDBC url:** jdbc:mysql://localhost/test_db

**Isolation level:** TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

**User:** root

**Password:** ••••••

**Language:** English

**Buffer size:** 100

**Sleep (ms):** 0

**Primary key:** id

**Unique key (for deletion):** id

**SQL Select:** SELECT * FROM tbl_test

**SQL Update:** (blank)

```
FieldMap settings

SQL Column    Index Field
------------------------------
title         title
description   metaDescription
url           url
```

When I save settings and execute the crawl process i get the following:-

```
Name        Execution time    Duration    Status     Info
test_crawl  8:47:44 PM        0:00:00     Complete   0 (0) / 39409 (0)
```

No documents are added to the index. Please will you let me know where I'm going wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- empy field "Unique key (for deletion)"
- add a field mapping between the primary key of your table with a field of your schema

Comment: Thank you very much, the new settings work perfectly